# How to do partial and full updates on a document using mgo in Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

From Web Development with Go by Shiju Varghese, about the update method in the MongoDB driver `mgo` in Go

> **Updating Documents**
>
> The Update method of the Collection type allows you
>   to update existing documents. Here is the method signature of the
>   Update method:
>
> ```
> func (c *Collection) Update(selector interface{}, update interface{}) error
> ```
>
> The Update method finds a single document from the collection, matches
>   it with the provided selector  document, and modifies it based on the
>   provided update document. A partial update can be done by using  the
>   keyword "$set" in the update document.
>
> Listing 8-14 updates an existing document.
>
> ```
> err := c.Update(bson.M{"_id": id},
> bson.M{"$set": bson.M{
> "description": "Create open-source projects",
> "tasks": []Task{
> Task{" Evaluate Negroni Project", time.Date(2015, time.August, 15, 0, 0, 0, 
> 0, time.UTC)},
> Task{" Explore mgo Project", time.Date(2015, time.August, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> time.UTC)},
> Task{" Explore Gorilla Toolkit", time.Date(2015, time.August, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> time.UTC)},
> },
> }})
> ```
>
> A partial update is performed for the fields’ descriptions and tasks.
>   The Update method finds the  document with the provided _id value and
>   modifies the fields based on the provided document.

The example is a partial update. It uses two-level nested `bson.M` to create `update interface{}`. Does a partial update always use such two-level nested `bson.M`?

Does a full update use one-level `bson.M`, such as

> ```
> err := c.Update(bson.M{"_id": id},
> bson.M{ "description": "Create open-source projects",
> "tasks": []Task{
> Task{" Evaluate Negroni Project", time.Date(2015, time.August, 15, 0, 0, 0, 
> 0, time.UTC)},
> Task{" Explore mgo Project", time.Date(2015, time.August, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> time.UTC)},
> Task{" Explore Gorilla Toolkit", time.Date(2015, time.August, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> time.UTC)},
> },
> })
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the partial update always requires `$set`. This is not about Go this is about Mongo <kbd>[$set operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)</kbd> `bson.M` is just the shortcut for `map[string]interface{}` which allows us to build JSON-like structures in go without thinking about argument type. So, as you always need `$set` the update document always will have at least two levels of `bson.M`. Actually, there are more levels as your `Task` objects could be defined as `bson.M` objects too.
2. Yes, the full document update (personally I think this process looks more like replace) requires only 2 `bson.M` objects - the query and the new document.

   In Mongo full update looks like

   `db.collection.update({_id: "id"}, {name: "name", num: 1})`

   And the same command in Go:

   `c.Update(bson.M{"_id": "id"}, bson.M{"name": "name", "num": 1})`